# Validate login form on jsp pages

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, sql-injection

Login Form (index2.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body bgcolor="96D2C2">

    <form name="ask_1" method="get" action="index24.jsp">
    Username: <input type="text" name="id11"/> <BR>
    Password: <input type="password" name="id22" /> <BR>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"  /> <BR>
    <BR>
    </form>
  <a href="index12.html"> Create an Account </a>
</body>
```

My JSP code in order to verify the login info and print to user success or not... (index24.jsp)`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 
 <% int j=0; %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <% 
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
   String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1?user=root&password=1234"; 
   Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);
   Statement myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();  
   String id11=request.getParameter("id11");
   String id22=request.getParameter("id22");
   String sqlString = "SELECT FROM users WHERE username='"+id11+"' AND password='"+id22+"' ";
   ResultSet rs = myStatement.executeQuery(sqlString);
   if(rs.next()) {
       System.out.println("Success"); }
   else {
       System.out.println("Failed");
   }

   %>


    </body>

</html>
```

The code given above is giving me the error, "The requested resource is not available.". Any suggestions and improvements to my code or edit are appreciated.

Comment: try to change the String myDatabase from that used one to : 
String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8080/mydb1?user=root&password=1234";

Comment: are you sure you're setting the mysql-connector in the web-inf folder !! if it is well done , by the way to establish a connection a database secured by password you shoud give it as parameter like this : Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1",
            "root", "1234");

Comment: i observe that in register form that i have , my db connects with the html page here not...

Comment: if u see i declare as statement myconnection above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was the server (GlassFish)... i used Apache Tomcat and works properly...

Answer (score 0):

the `Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myDatabase);`
is kind wrong because the `getConnection()`  will not handle the url given as parameter String try to do it like this :

```
Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb1" , "root" , "1234");
```

you can check the documentation of that method , and dont'forhet to remove this line

```
String myDatabase = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb1?user=root&password=1234";
```

Comment: same promblem i think its another the promblem not the connection between the DB

Comment: Finally the problem was the server (GlassFish)... i have used Apache Tomcat and works properly...

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the "try {" block with

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(out));
}
```

to get more details about the error. It is a simple trick for developing jsps and should be removed in an official version of a web-site.

Also, it may be out of topic, but your code is susceptible to SQL injection. See more here
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp